# What are the "diminishing returns" for phaselocking the same enemy?

Tags: borderlands-2

One of the loading screens proclaims that phaselocking the same enemy multiple times results in "diminishing returns". I've never particularly noticed this effect myself, but I find I rarely phaselock the same non-boss enemy twice, and if I phaselock a boss it's mostly "just because", the damage you deal to enemies you can't "lock" in place is minimal at my level.

What exactly are the diminishing returns? I assume Phaselock does less damage/doesn't hold as long, but what's the formula for it? Does it affect skills like Ruin and Helios which do extra damage upon Phaselocking as well?

Comment: I can't be certain, but I think I've seen my phaselock last shorter periods when used on the same enemy.  Mind you, this would be on badasses and uniques, which I believe already spend a shorter time in phaselock.

Answer (score 2):

Diminishing Returns means if you keep phase-locking same enemy again and again it will be less effective on him. It will be doing less damage, less time duration of effect.

I Assume it will affect the skills as well because Phaselock cant damage on its own you need to have other skills (chaos tree) to make it more useful.

Comment: But how much? I can pretty much guess that much as I state in the question, but what's the relative or exact factor? And phaselock does damage on it's own to enemies it can't hold (mostly bosses and Threshers)